# Operation on data frame to transform rows into separate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a data-frame containing following structure

```
    **Email             MAC**                   
    email_1@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A1      
    email_1@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A5      
    email_1@mail.com    PP:PP:PP:PP:P5
    email_1@mail.com    PP:PP:PP:PP:P6
    email_2@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A2
    email_2@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A9
```

I have to settle them into

```
**Email             MAC1                    MAC2                        MAC3**
email_1@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A1      AA:AA:AA:AA:A5              PP:PP:PP:PP:P5
email_2@mail.com    AA:AA:AA:AA:A2      AA:AA:AA:AA:A9              Null
```

The value PP:PP:PP:PP:P6 corresponding to email_1@mail.com has been discarded as it exceeds the number of allowed columns(only first 3 values are allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter column, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
N = 3
g = df.groupby('Email').cumcount().add(1)
df = df[g <= N]
df1 = df.set_index(['Email',g[g<=N]])['MAC'].unstack().add_prefix('MAC').reset_index()
print (df1)
              Email            MAC1            MAC2            MAC3
0  email_1@mail.com  AA:AA:AA:AA:A1  AA:AA:AA:AA:A5  PP:PP:PP:PP:P5
1  email_2@mail.com  AA:AA:AA:AA:A2  AA:AA:AA:AA:A9             NaN
```